# C malloc use case - realloc versus pre-computation

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I want to create an array of structs on the heap from another data structure. Say there are N total elements to traverse, and (N-x) pointers (computed_elements) will be added to the array.

My naive strategy for this is to create an array (temp_array) size N on the stack and traverse the data structure, keeping track of how many elements need to be added to the array, and adding them to temp_array when I encounter them. Once I've finished, I malloc(computed_elements) and populate this array with the temp_array.

This is suboptimal because the second loop is unnecessary. However, I am weighing this against the tradeoff of constantly reallocating memory every iteration. Some rough code to clarify:

```
void *temp_array[N];
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  if (check(arr[i])) {
    temp_array[count] = arr[i];
    count++;
  }
}

void *results = malloc(count * sizeof(MyStruct));
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  results[i] = temp_array[i];
}

return results;
```

Thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you incrementing `count` somewhere?

Comment: Your approach seems fine to me. Allocation functions are very expensive.

Comment: @imreal Expensive as in requiring many CPU cycles?

Comment: @FiddlingBits: No, as in requiring OS calls.

Comment: There are possibly OS calls and there are possibly large/many memory movements required.

Comment: @imreal: corrected the code to increment count.

Comment: This code won't work as shown. (Won't even compile.) `count` is never incremented.

Comment: What does `check(arr[i])` do?

Comment: @CareyGregory - yup, just edited it!

Comment: @FiddlingBits you can percieve it as a black box. It basically checks if an input element should be added to the result array.

Comment: Please help me keep my OCD under control and change this `(check(arr[i])` to this `(check(arr[i]))`. ;-)

Comment: Is it possible `results` may be as large as `arr`?  If that is so, assume worst case.

Comment: IMO - Premature optimization can cause a lot of complexity often with little benefit.  Then once justified, take measurements before and after your effort, sometimes your performance measures don't work as well as you envision.

Comment: One additional factor to take into account is the size of temp_array if it's placed on the stack.  Coming from an embedded world, we have to play close attention to our stack size

Answer (score 3):

One common strategy is to try to estimate the number of elements you're going to need (not a close estimate, more of a "On the order of..." type estimate).  Malloc that amount of memory, and when you get "close" to that limit ("close" also being up for interpretation), realloc some more.  Personally, I typically double the array when I get close to filling it.

**-EDIT-**

Here is the "ten minute version".  (I've ensured that it builds and doesn't segfault)

Obviously I've omitted things like checking for the success of malloc/realloc, zeroing memory, etc...

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>     /* for the "malloc only version" (see below) */

/* Assume 500 elements estimated*/
#define ESTIMATED_NUMBER_OF_RECORDS   500

/* "MAX" number of elements that the original question seems to be bound by */
#define N   10000

/* Included only to allow for test compilation */
typedef struct
{
    int foo;
    int bar;
} MyStruct;

/* Included only to allow for test compilation */
MyStruct arr[N] = { 0 };

/* Included only to allow for test compilation */
bool check(MyStruct valueToCheck)
{
    bool baz = true;
    /* ... */
    return baz;
}

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    int idx = 0;
    int actualRecordCount = 0;
    int allocatedSize = 0;
    MyStruct *tempPointer = NULL;

    MyStruct *results = malloc(ESTIMATED_NUMBER_OF_RECORDS * sizeof(MyStruct));
    allocatedSize = ESTIMATED_NUMBER_OF_RECORDS;

    for (idx = 0; idx < N; idx++)
    {
        /* Ensure that we're not about to walk off the current array */
        if (actualRecordCount == (allocatedSize))
        {
            allocatedSize *= 2;

            /* "malloc only version"
             * If you want to avoid realloc and just malloc everything...
             */
            /*
            tempPointer = malloc(allocatedSize);
            memcpy(tempPointer, results, allocatedSize);
            free(results);
            results = tempPointer;
            */

            /* Using realloc... */
            tempPointer = realloc(results, allocatedSize);
            results = tempPointer;
        }

        /* Check validity or original array element */
        if (check(arr[idx]))
        {
            results[actualRecordCount] = arr[idx];
            actualRecordCount++;
        }
    }

    if (results != NULL)
    {
        free(results);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Depends on your how limited your resources (i.e. RAM) are and how large the `struct`s are.

Comment: Another heuristic is to use something like `newsize = 3*oldsize/2 + 50;` : this grows quickly small arrays, but for huge arrays waste only half size at most.

Comment: Is the code complexity worth it? Versus just pre-computing the size and then re-traversing as done in my snippet. I am not dealing with an insane amount of data, something like 1000 or so elements.

Comment: Good point @BasileStarynkevitch.  I didn't want to seem like I was being overly-specific, but yes, you should try to intelligently pick your new array size

Comment: well, using realloc + a few equations isn't as complex as it may sound.  I'd throw up some code, but I'm on my wife's tablet with software keyboard.  I'll add an example tomorrw

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is malloc for the size `N`, then run your loop, then realloc for size `N-x`. Memory fragmentation may result for small x.

Answer (score 0):

The best re-usable code very often is **scalable**.  Unless obligated to use small sizes, assume code will grow in subsequent applications and need to be reasonable efficient for large N.  You do want to re-use good code.

`realloc()` an array by a factor of 4 or so as the need arises.  Arrays may also shrink - no need to have a bloated array laying around.  I've used grow by factor of 4 at intervals 1,4,16,64... and shrink intervals at 2,8,32,128...   By having grow/shrink intervals apart from each other, it avoid lots of actively should N waver around an interval.

Even in small ways, like using `size_t` vs. `int`.  Sure, with sizes like 1000, it makes no difference, but with code re-use, an application may push the limit: `size_t` is better for array indexes.

```
void *temp_array[N];
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {

void *temp_array[N];
for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
```